# Some basic C++ concepts — initialization and assignment

Tags: c++

I was asked in an interview, to tell the exact difference for the following c/c++ code statements

```
int a = 10;
```

and

```
int a;
a = 10;
```

Though both assign the same value, they told me there is a lot of difference between the two in memory.

Can anyone please explain to me about this?

Comment: `int a = 10` *initializes* `a` with value `10`. `a = 10` *assigns* the value `10` to an already initialized `int a`.

Comment: What actually confuses you?? _"But there is a lot of difference between the two in memory."_ There isn't a difference in memory, where did you get this concept from?!?

Comment: in memory? What is this a lot of difference?

Comment: Please don't dual-tag questions with C and C++.  They are two very different languages.  The subtleties that apply to C++ in a full description of the difference between assignment and initialization (for a type more complex than `int`) are vast.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Doesn't really matter much for this particular case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: yes (for `int` there is very little difference) and my comment says as much, but a worthwhile answer for C++ as specified in the title should cover a lot of ground.  There's probably a duplicate for this somewhere (but the related questions a MIA again).

Comment: this question was asked to me in an interview today

Comment: @JonathanLeffler May be (after clarification from OP's side), the tag should have been left, because there are in fact differences. If you leave the variable declaration uninitialized in c code (remember you'll need to declare them at the very beginning of the current scope block), delayed initialization might lead to more efficient code (my colleague once explained that for me, and he's a real c crack, still denying to learn c++ at least ;-)).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Only C89 requires variables defined at the start of a block; C99 and C11 both allow variables defined anywhere in a block, essentially the same as C++.  It is time to let C89 be the archaic and obsolete language it should be.  (Don't get me wrong: C89 was a truly remarkable standard that did a fabulous job.  And C99 has some warts.  But it is time to move beyond C89.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Could well be the interview question might refer to older standards, doesn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And it doesn't matter about block local definitions (see _@Igor_'s little intermezzo on my answer), nor c or c++. It's kind of micro optimization for small targets, to have `a` uninitialized for a more efficient code footprint IMHO.

Comment: @sahilsikka I'd appreciate, if you'd let me know if my answer and reasoning makes any sense for you, or elaborate what this interview question exactly was about (and what was told you, why you failed it, if so).

Answer (score 4):

As far as language concerned, they are two ways to do the **same** thing, **initialize** the variable `a` and **assign** 10 to it.

The statement
`int a;` **reserves memory** for the value a which certainly contains garbage.

Because of that you **initialize** it with `a = 10;`

In the statement `int a = 10;` these two steps are done in the **same** statement.

First a part of memory is **reserved** to the variable `a`, and then the memory is **overwritten** with the value of `10`.

```
int a                                     =  10;
^^^^^                                     ^^^^^
reserve memory for the variable a         write 10 to that memory location
```

Regarding memory the first declaration uses less memory on your PC because less characters are used, so your `.c` file will be smaller.

But **after compilation** the produced executable files will be the **same**.

**IMPORTANT**: if those statements are outside any function they are possibly not the same (although they will produce the same result).

The problem is that the first statement will assign `0` to `a` in the first statement because most compilers do that to **global** variables in C (and is defined by C standard).

Comment: can u please explain me this in more detail

Comment: @Igor "Regarding memory the first declaration uses less memory on your PC because less characters are used" All what you're telling here is plain rubbish (or at least not very well comprehensible), regarding that interview question. I don't think you'd pass there :P ...

Comment: @AntonSavin Sorry, wrongly addressed in 1st place. Though, the upvote certainly wasn't deserved for this crappy answer!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Please explain why it is crappy.

Comment: At least I don't have a clue about what you're talking there, and how this is related to differences in memory usage (where I doubt the interview question asked about memory usage during compilation).

Comment: Eh, it was a brief comic relief.

Answer (score 3):

> "Though both assign the same value, but there is a lot of difference between the two in memory."

No, there's no difference in stack memory usage!
The difference is that assigning a value though initialization may cause some extra cost for additional assembler instructions (and thus memory needed to store it, aka. *code footprint*), the compiler can't optimize out at this point (because it's demanded).

If you initialize `a` immediately this will have some cost in code. You might want to delay initialization for later use, when the value of `a` is actually needed:

```
void foo(int x) {
    int a; // int a = 30; may generate unwanted extra assembler instructions!

    switch(x) {
    case 0:
        a = 10;
        break;
    case 1:
        a = 20;
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }

    // Do something with a correctly initialized a
}
```

This could have well been an interview question made to you in our company, by particular colleagues of mine. And they'd wanted you to answer, that just having the declaration for `int a;` in 1st place is the more efficient choice.

I'd say this interview question was made to see, if you're really have an in-depth understanding of c and c++ language (A mean-spirited though!).

---

Speaking for me personally, I'm more convenient on interviews about such stuff usually.

I consider the effect is just very minimal. Though it could well seriously matter on embedded MCU targets, where you have very limited space left for the code footprint (say less/equal than 256K), and/or need to use compiler toolchains that actually aren't able to optimize this out for themselves.

Comment: Actually in your sample the compiler will produce the same code even if you write for example `int a = 30`, because it will see that the initial value is unused. You have to provide better example :)

Comment: @AntonSavin There's no guarantee the compiler sees it's not used, and optimizes initialization out. At least I'm pretty sure for older standards. Could you cite a standards paragraph proving your claims please?

Comment: No guarantee, true. But both gcc and clang do it. Standard says that `conforming
implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine`.

Comment: @AntonSavin As mentioned, this kind of interview questions apply, if we want to know if the apprentice has experience (spirit of) embedded programming, where these optimizations might not be taken in at first place with the available toolchains.

Comment: Well, if we are talking about compilers from 80s then maybe, but I believe most modern compilers will make this kind of optimization for any MCU because it's architecture-independent. At least I just tested on Android NDK compilers - results are the same.

Comment: @AntonSavin No not from the 80*s. Sorry there's still a lot of crappy compilers in use, you'll need to use for some brandnew silicon. Blame the manufacturers not me, that's embedded world :P ... It's about the apprentice's conception and awareness of such stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a global variable (one that doesn't appear in a block of code, but outside of all functions/methods):

```
int a;
```

makes a zero-initialized variable. Some (most?) c++ implementations will place this variable in a memory place (segment? section? whatever it is called) dedicated for zero-initialized variables.

```
int a = 10;
```

makes a variable initialized to something other than 0. Some implementations have a different region in memory for these. So this variable may have an address (`&a`) that is very different from the previous case.

This is, I guess, what you mean by "lot of difference between the two in memory".

Practically, this can affect your program if it has severe bugs (memory overruns) - they may get masked if `a` is defined in one manner or the other.

P.S. To make it clear, I am only talking about global variables here. So if your code is like `int main() {int a; a = 10;}` - here `a` is typically allocated on stack and there is no "difference in memory" between initialization and assignment.

Comment: look there are two methods to declare a variable and intialise main()                                                               {                                                                   int a;                                                              a=10;} and the other one is                                           main{int a=10;} so i am talking about the difference in this weather it takes less or more memory or else the value is the main difference

Comment: @sahilsikka _More memory_ for what? Code or stack?